# FormData textarea puts \r (carriage return) when sent with POST

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

Why does `FormData` insert carriage returns before line feed characters?

When I send post request with `FormData`, it uses CRLF line endings, even though the value of textarea has no carriage returns at all. This makes my character length validation fail unexpectedly.

The sample code below shows the difference between the textarea string value, the data in `FormData` and the encoded data that will get submitted. `JSON.stringify()` is used to escape the control characters.

```js
document.getElementById('HistoryValue').textContent = JSON.stringify(document.forms.CRLFSample.history.value);
const fd = new FormData(document.forms.CRLFSample);
document.getElementById('FormData').textContent = JSON.stringify(fd.get('history'));
new Response(fd).text().then(text =>
document.getElementById('POSTData').textContent = JSON.stringify(text));
```

```css
#CRLFSample {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<form id="CRLFSample" method="POST">
  <textarea name="history">
    line 1
    line 2
  </textarea>
</form>
<dl>
<dt>Textarea</dt><dd id="HistoryValue"></dd>
<dt>FormData</dt><dd id="FormData"></dd>
<dt>POST data</dt><dd id="POSTData"></dd>
</dl>
```

The above has been tested in Firefox 92-94 and Chrome 95 on macOS 10.14 & 12 and Android 10. Note "Textarea" shows "\n" for newlines, but "POSTData" has "\r\n". "FormData" shows different results depending mostly on the browser, with most versions of FireFox showing just "\n" and most versions of Chrome showing "\r\n".

### Edited by original asker below

Didn't think I had this many comments. Thank you for your interests, and allow me to apologize for not observing site guide lines. I'll try to elaborate more to best help you to reproduce the error and understand what's going on.

I tested this on my mac Catalina 10.15.7 and my browser is chrome Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (x86_64).

Below is my attempt to validate char length with formdata and just grabbing value of textarea respectively.

```js
let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
let historyEl = document.getElementById('id_history');
console.log(formData.get('history').length, formData.get('history').includes('\r\n'));
console.log(historyEl.value.length, historyEl.value.includes('r\n'));
```

```html
<form id="form" method="POST">
<textarea class="materialize-textarea" cols="40" name="history" id="id_history" rows="10">    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
make a type 
specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also 
the leap into electronic 
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in 
the 190
.</textarea>
</form>
```

As you can see by running code snippet, formdata length of `history` shows different length than that of textarea element value.

Originally I received the textarea value from Window user, and I thought it was only the matter of OS. But when I inspected it, that even happens in my OS, especially when submitting with form data.

One might ask that I can inspect length of textarea value, but I try to avoid that because checking with formdata is the whole point of frontend validation.

I'm not native English speaker, and my char length validation was on other non latin language, but something prevents me from posting non-latin language in code snippet. But Since console yields different lengths respectively, I believe you'll get the idea with other chars anyway.

Comment: Can you share your areatext html ? And the JS coder that belongs to the question?

Comment: I've edited the question for reproduction.

Comment: thanks. i updated my answear. tell me if it useful for you.

Comment: It used to be specified that textarea's `value` for form submission should be normalized with CRLF, but since https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/6697 that should be LF only now, quite weird browsers didn't catch up...

Comment: What platform did you test? What browsers did you test? What is the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you used to test? What was received server-side?

Comment: @outis here is a repro: https://jsfiddle.net/9zd6qpk1/ happens in both FF and Chrome on my macOS system.

Comment: @Kaiido: all information should be added to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [sample code guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), not [left as comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) or [linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: ... Note that adding a link to a live example *in addition* to having code in the question is welcomed. For HTML, CSS an JS, the [Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/90527) feature allows you to create a [live example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/90527) on SO itself.

Comment: @outis I am not the asker, I am merely trying to see if you can also repro or if this is just an OS matter, in my quality of "potential answerer", and as a WHATWG member in case specs need to change to follow browser's behavior and as a browser bug reporter. This is I believe a well suited use of the comments: asking the ones that seem to not be able tp reproduce if they just didn't try or were really unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Kaiido: I saw that you weren't the OP. Even so, information that's relevant to the question should be added to the question (for all the reasons in the site guidelines). If a comment is requesting additional info, it's because it's missing from the question; it's not the responsibility of a potential answerer to guess at what the OP means and try to reproduce an issue based on partial information. In any case, I appreciate that you took the time to supply the missing information, and the question now contains enough to be reproducible, so I've voted to re-open.

Comment: @outis you mean that the snippet now reproduces the issue on your side? It doesn't for me. And that's why I only posted it as a comment and not as an edit: I don't know if OP sees what I do see, moreover given your comment that was implying that you weren't seeing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238881/discussion-between-outis-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to MDN, [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) uses the "multipart/form-data" format, specified by [RFC 2388, section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388.html#section-3) of which states:

> The media-type multipart/form-data follows the rules of all multipart MIME data streams as outlined in RFC 2046.

[RFC § 4.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.1.1), the section on line endings, states:

> The canonical form of any MIME "text" subtype MUST always represent a line break as a CRLF sequence.

Which is why line endings get encoded as CRLF when posted. What is not clear from this is whether line endings should be encoded as CRLF in `FormData`'s entries (such as shown by the result of `formData.get('history')`).

The [spec for `FormData`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-formdata) makes no mention of encoding line endings when adding an entry or value. The only processing of a value when being added is for [Blob](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob) (i.e. binary) and [File](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-file) objects. No processing of the value by [`FormData.get()`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-formdata-get) is mentioned. A strict reading of this would be that Chrome's behavior (encoding values stored in `FormData`) is non-standard. However, storing a value directly would mean that the browser's internal (likely the platform's) line ending encoding would be used, which might vary.

The [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) designates [`Response`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response) as being responsible for handling the multipart/form-data encoding; specifically, [extracting](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract) `FormData` is supposed to use the ["multipart/form-data" encoding algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#multipart/form-data-encoding-algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

You have linebreaks inside your textarea. I can think of two ways to avoid this problem. I am sure there are several other possibilities.

In this case you can collect the data and remove/replace the \n \r 's with a js replace function.  like so:

```
const text = fd.get('history')
console.log('out1:',text)
console.log('out2:', text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ""));
```

Or you add a eventlistener to the textarea which recognises that a return has been entered and deletes it immediately.

```
document.querySelector('textarea[name=history]').onkeydown = function( e ) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
  {      
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('your code to remove immediately the line break/return')
  }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is, it's not that I don't know how to fix this. It's more like I'm wondering whether I have to replace carriage return with empty string whenever my textarea has line break or carriage return. Is this sort of default behavior or FormData?

Comment: @harryghgim that you can insert linebreaks in a textarea is the purpose of this element. otherwise you should take input.

Comment: If you inspect the value of textarea in Mac, it will show a bunch of `\n`s. I'm ok with that. The problem is however even though I'm using mac, whenever I send the form and inspect formdata using get api, I see `\r\n`s, not `\n`s. That's what confuses me.

Comment: @harryghgim I understand. im linuxuser :-) It is probably an OS issue.

Comment: Does the same thing happen in linux? I know linux also uses \n. When you inspect form data when it's sent through POST, do `\n`s get replaced wth `\r\n`s?

Comment: @harryghgim Windows uses a pair of CR and LF characters to end a line. UNIX (Linux and FreeBSD) uses only one LF character. OS X also uses a single LF character. But the classic Mac operating system used a single CR character for the line break. Wow! 8-)

Comment: I think a more reasonable replace would be `.replace(/(\r?\n)/g, '\r\n')`, which won't leave the string without any breaks at all.